# JavaScript how to get text value by clicking and then display the value in another html tag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm really new to JavaScript.

I have a html like this:

```
<li><a class="dropdown-item confirm" href="#">wtdata</a></li>
```

How can I use js to click this link and get 'wtdata' ,then display the value **'wtdata'** in here:

```
<h5  id="staticBackdropLabel">You want to run wtdata ?</h5>
```

Comment: So add an event listener, read the textContent, select the other element, and update the textContent of the other element.

Comment: This is so 101 I cannot even find a good example. Please check out [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) [preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `onClick` event to your `<a/>` tag, then use `innerText` attribute. like this

```js
const a = document.getElementById("a");
a.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  const staticBackdropLabel = document.getElementById("staticBackdropLabel");
  staticBackdropLabel.innerText = e.target.innerText;
});
```

```html
<li><a id="a" class="dropdown-item confirm" href="#">wtdata</a></li>

<h5 id="staticBackdropLabel">You want to run wtdata ?</h5>
```

Comment: Hi Sir ,thank you so much for your reply,can you help me with this one also:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74030947/javascript-check-2-conditions-by-clicking-link-and-confirm-pop-window

Comment: This post is invalid...

Comment: Hi I just reopened it

Answer (score 1):

```js
function getValue() {
    document.getElementById("staticBackdropLabel").innerText = document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].innerText;
}
```

```html
<li  onclick="getValue()"><a class="dropdown-item confirm" href="#">wtdata</a></li>
<h5  id="staticBackdropLabel">You want to run wtdata ?</h5>
```

Comment: Hi Sir ,thank you so much for your reply,can you help me with this one also:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74030947/javascript-check-2-conditions-by-clicking-link-and-confirm-pop-window

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to handle the click on the `a` to get the value of the tag, and then display it in your `h5`

```
// Handle click on the link
document.querySelector('.dropdown-item.confirm').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  // Retrieve your h5 by its ID
  const title = document.querySelector('#staticBackdropLabel');
  // Change the content
  title.textContent = event.target.textContent
});
```

I prefer `querySelector` over `getElementsByClassname`, you don't have to get the `[0]` element with `querySelector` :

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Comment: Hi Sir ,thank you so much for your reply,can you help me with this one also:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74030947/javascript-check-2-conditions-by-clicking-link-and-confirm-pop-window