# How can I check two conditions by clicking link and confirm pop window?

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

I'm new to JavaScript and have 2 html links:

```
<li><a class="dropdown-item confirm" href="#">wtdata</a></li>
<li><a class="dropdown-item confirm" href="#">ftdata</a></li>
```

The first step is getting the specific text value by clicking each link. For example, if I click the first link I will get the text wtdata. If I click the second link, I get the text ftdata. I have completed this step by:

```
<script>

var myFunction = function() {
    var attribute = this.innerHTML;
    alert(attribute);
};

var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-item");

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
}

</script>
```

After clicking the link in last step, a Bootstrap modal will automatically pop out which has 2 buttons. This is a built-in Bootstrap function, already done. The buttons are:

```
  <button id='cancel_btn'>Cancel</button>
  <button id='confirm_btn'>Confirm</button>
```

The second step is:

If in the first step link wtdata is clicked and Confirm button in pop windows has been clicked,then replace the href value of link wtdata with 'wtdata_url'.

Same as link ftdata,if
in the first step link ftdata is clicked and Confirm button in pop window has been clicked ,replace the href value of link ftdata with 'ftdata_url'.

How to complete the second step?I have tried build a function to return the specific text that has been clicked ,but I can't get the return value:

```
 <script>       
    function getLinkname(cl){
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(cl);
    var getText = function() {
    var attribute = this.innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("staticBackdropLabel").innerHTML='Run ' + attribute + ' ?';
    

};
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].addEventListener('click', getText, false);
}
return attribute;
    }

    var linkname = getLinkname('confirm');
    console.log(linkname);

  </script>
```

error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: attribute is not defined
    at getLinkname ((index):159:1)
```

Comment: What is your question? Where did you got stuck? Please add a [mre]!

Comment: Thank you for your reply,I'm modifying it.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

This example I wrote is based on my undertanding about your question.

- I use the `id` attribute, because it is a simple way.
- If you want to change innerText of `<a/>` tag **dynamically**, the better way is to produce your `<ul/>` link list by JavaScript.

```js
function clickATag (e) {
  document.getElementById('input').value = e.innerText
  document.getElementById('aTagId').innerText = e.id
  
  var myModal = getMyModal();
  myModal.show()
}

function clickButton (e) {
  const aTagId = document.getElementById('aTagId').innerText;
  const a = document.getElementById(aTagId);
  a.innerText = document.getElementById("input").value;
  
  const result = document.getElementById('result');
  result.innerText = "new url: " + document.getElementById("input").value;
}

function getMyModal () {
  var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('myModal'), {
  keyboard: false
  })
  
  return myModal;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<ul>
<li><a id="a1" class="dropdown-item confirm" href="#" onclick="clickATag(this)">wtdata</a></li>
<li><a id="a2" class="dropdown-item confirm" href="#" onclick="clickATag(this)">ftdata</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="myModal" class="modal" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <input id="input" />
        <p id="result">new url:</p>
        <p id="aTagId" hidden></p>
        <p>Buttons</p>
        <button id='cancel_btn' type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="clickButton(this)">Confirm</button>
        <button id='confirm_btn' type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Cancel</button> 
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```